# How to display column chart values based on a total value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm currently using a 100% stacked column chart (not sure if this is what I should be using). I have two measures [Amount Transmitted] and [Amount Awarded] as my values. [Award Categories] is my X-Axis. What I'm attempting to do is display the amount transmitted out of the overall amount awarded. Amount awarded being my total(100%). For example, let's say for a specific award category, an amount transmitted was 60$, and my amount awarded was 120$. The amount transmitted line should be at 50%. However, this is not what is happening. Instead, the chart is adding 60$ + 120$ and making the overall 180$. How can I achieve what I have in mind ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're plotting the wrong measures. Of course, if you stack 120 and 60, that will be 180 and using that as a percentage will mean that 60 is 33% of the total, not 50%

You need to calculate what's left when you subtract the amount transmitted from the amount awarded (120 - 60 = 60) and then stack the amount transmitted on top of the **reduced** amount awarded (or the difference between transmitted and awarded). That will then be 120 total and 60 will count as 50% of the total.

So, create these three measures

- amount transmitted
- amount awarded
- amount difference =[amount awarded] - [amount transmitted])

Use these measures as values in the stacked 100% chart: [amount transmitted]  and [amount difference]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!